# use of extern keyword with CHandle for win32 events

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to use win32 event across 2 files. So I'm using extern.
Basically I'm signaling a thread from main thread and thread procedure is in different file. 
I am getting some error msg : unresolved external symbol:

ThreadProcedure.cpp:

```
#include<process.h>
#include<afxmt.h>
#include<afxwin.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

UINT __cdecl MyThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{

    extern CHandle hEvent;
    cout << "waiting for getting signal..." << endl;
    DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    cout << "signaled" << endl;
    // Terminate the thread
    ::AfxEndThread(0, FALSE);
    return 0L;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<process.h>
#include<afxmt.h>
#include<afxwin.h>
using namespace std;
#include"Header.h"

UINT __cdecl MyThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter);
HANDLE     hEvent;

void main()
{

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, L"AnEvent");

    CWinThread* pThread;
    pThread = ::AfxBeginThread(&MyThreadProc, NULL, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
    pThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
    pThread->ResumeThread();

    ::WaitForSingleObject(pThread->m_hThread, INFINITE);
    delete pThread;

    system("pause");
}
```

ERROR:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ATL::CHandle hEvent" (?hEvent@@3VCHandle@ATL@@A)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main.cpp you define a `HANDLE hEvent`, in ThreadProcedure.cpp you declare an extern `CHandle hEvent`. Surely those are not identical. So the linker is right, he does not find any `CHandle hEvent`, only a `HANDLE hEvent`. You need to give the same type in the declaration (in ThreadProcedure.cpp) and in the definition (in main.cpp).

ThreadProcedure.cpp:

```
extern HANDLE hEvent;
```

Some other remarks regarding your code: you are passing C++ bool `true`/`false` to `CreateEvent`. `CreateEvent` requires `BOOL` parameters, thus `TRUE` and `FALSE`. In my opinion it is better style to pass `TRUE`/`FALSE` than the C++ `true`/`false` which the compiler needs to cast to `BOOL`.

Also don't write `using namespace std;` in any header or before an `#include` (in your case in main.cpp before `#include "Header.h"`.

Comment: As I wrote in the last sentence of my answer.